# How to merge 2 rows into 1 row at the same column using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I just started using the UNIX and also no much experience in scripting. Now I am struggling a lot to merge the 2 rows at the same column. Below is original data.
There columns are split into 2 rows but ideally should be in 1 row. 
But I don't know how to do it.

## Original File

```
User   Middle   Last  
Name   Name     Name
Htat   Ko       Lin
John   Smith    Bill
```

## Trying to achieve:

```
UserName   MiddleName   LastName  
Htat       Ko           Lin
John       Smith        Bill
```

Thanks!
Htat Ko

Comment: Is the column alignment important?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using awk and for loops

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i;next}NR==2{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=a[i]$i}1' file
```

---

#### Output

```
UserName   MiddleName   LastName  
Htat       Ko           Lin
John       Smith        Bill
```

---

#### Explanation

```
NR==1
```

If the record number is 1. i.e the first record then execute the next block

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
```

Loop from one to the number of fields(`NF`).Incrementing by one each time.

```
a[i]=$i
```

Using `i` as a key set an array element in the array `a` to the field i (`$i`).

```
next
```

Skip all further instruction and move to the next record.

```
NR==2
```

Same as before but for record 2

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
```

Exactly the same as before

```
$i=a[i]$i
```

Set field `i` to the stored value in the array and then itself

```
1
```

Defaults to true so prints all lines unless next has been used

---

#### Additional notes

if you want keep the columns in line the easiest was to do this is to pipe that command into `column -t`

```
awk '...' file | column -t
```

---

Reduced version

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)(NR==2&&$i=a[i]$i)||a[i]=$i}NR>1' file
```